# Wordpress P2 live problem

Tags: ajax, theme-p2

Everything worked perfectly in localhost. When I uploaded everything online, the ajax submission seems to not working. It's refreshing the page for comments and live updated is not working

I have this which appear when i'm on my online server (console):
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

For the function :
locale = new wp.locale( wpLocale ),

I don't have this error when I'm in localhost.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Have you set the locale? Perhaps that is missing from the remote server.